# Missing hadoop conf files Docker Kylin 5

Tags: kylin

Last Docker image update Kylin 5.0 I have an error after command $KYLIN_HOME/bin/sample.sh
`Missing hadoop conf files. Please contact Community support for more details.`

Try $KYLIN_HOME/bin/check-env.sh

```
============================================================================
Checking check-1200-hadoop-conf.sh
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Retrieving hadoop config dir...
Missing hadoop conf files. Please contact Community support for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

same issue has been discussed here: https://blog.csdn.net/huawuqing/article/details/130723279

Following is a brief translation :

1. In docker conteainer find file */home/kylin/entrypoint.sh*. Before *#init shchema for hive* add code:

```
  if [ ! -f "/home/kylin/first_run" ]
   then
       $KYLIN_HOME/sbin/download-spark-user.sh
   fi
```

2. After *#start kylin* comment code line:

```
   $KYLIN_HOME/sbin/download-spark-user.sh
```

3. Delete file */home/kylin/first_run* if exists. Run */home/kylin/entrypoint.sh*
4. When promted

```
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory root= /data/hadoop/dfs/name; location= null ? (Y or N)
```

type *Y*

It works for me.